# JPA namedQuery: select delivers only first entry

Tags: named-query

this is my problem:
I have a DB-table like:

`CFG_NAME | CFG_CLASS_NAME
cfg1     | class1
cfg1     | class2
cfg1     | class3`

an my namedQuery is: 
`@NamedQuery(name = "getCfgClassByName", query = "SELECT e FROM CfgClasses e WHERE e.cfgName = :name") })`

my select looks like this:

`TypedQuery namedQuery = em.createNamedQuery("getCfgClassByName", CfgClasses.class).setParameter("name", "cfg1");
List result = tq.getResultList();
result -> only one entry (the first in the table)`

where is my fault?

Comment: pls show the mapped class

Comment: @Id
 @Column(name = "CFG_NAME", insertable = true)
 private String cfgName;
 @Column(name = "CFG_CLASS_NAME", insertable = true)
 private String cfgClassName;

Comment: if `cfName` is a an `@Id`, it has be unique, but your table has repeated values.